# Effect of start-stop technology in accessory belt drive system life, of automotive engines

Tags: belt-tensioner, drive-belt

Does start-stop technology (In Cars/Trucks) during traffic stops cause significant reduction in life for the accessory belt and tensioner system in engines?

Assumptions
1) The belt and tensioner system are subjected to a fluctuating load during the start of the engine.

Comment: I cannot imagine that it would have any significant effect on the belt and tensioner since big load differences are very normal for the accessory system. Take for example the A/C clutch switching on and off and different loads caused by the alternator and power steering pump.

Comment: No reduction in lifespan at all. Belts get far more stress with engine running and driving than just starting it.